# Why always return null when call the method IQueryable.FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, expression

```
 public class CellValue
{
    double? Max;
    double? Min;
    string  Value;
    string Annotation;
}

    public T GetOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate）
｛
     IQueryable<T> query = this.context.Set<T>();
     return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
｝

    public class Steel: CellValue{}

    CellValue cell = new CellValue{Max = 0.8, Min = 0.1, Value="test"};
    Steel steel = service.GetOne(t=>t.Max == cell.Max && t.Min == cell.Min && t.Value ==cell.Value && t.Annotation == cell.Annotation);
    //but the object steel is always null. Jush Why？
```

I checked my database, but i dont know it's always null.Expression Tree and Lambda Expression may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "OrDefault" methods return null for reference types, or default value for value types (e.g int is a value type, so it will return 0).

Comment: I make sure it's reference type.